# JSESSIONID and CSRF-TOKEN Spring security filters

Tags: csrf, jsessionid

Which concrete filters, provided by Spring Security components, to be responsible for the 'doFilter' work for the **JSESSIONID** and **CSRF-Token** respectively? E.g. *UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter* to handle Login Form posted from client.

Comment: Currently, the spring security framework I am using is 4.0.3.RELEASE

Comment: Have you found the answer meanwhile? I have the same question now. Thank you